# Knockout JS and Wijmo dialog nested binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding, viewmodel, wijmo

I have this View-Model structure:

```
function PluginViewModel(name, code) {
  var self = this;

  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.code = ko.observable(code);
}

function item() {
 var self = this;

 self.id = ko.observable();
 self.listIndex = ko.observable();
 self.value = ko.observable();
 self.label = ko.observable();
 self.tabPos = ko.observable();
 self.plugins = ko.observableArray();
};

function TableViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.columns = ko.observableArray();
self.filteredColumns = ko.observableArray();

// To bind View Fields List
self.selectedColumn = ko.observable();
self.selectColumn = function (p) {
    self.selectedColumn(p);
}

// To bind Table Columns List
self.tmpColSelected = ko.observable();
self.tmpColSelect = function (p) {
    self.tmpColSelected(p);
}

// Plugin selected
self.selectedPlugin = ko.observable();
self.selectPlugin = function (p) {
    self.selectedPlugin(p);
}

// New Plugin
self.newPlugin = ko.observable();
self.addPlugin = function () {
    self.selectedColumn().plugins.push(self.newPlugin());

    $('#dialogAddPlugin').wijdialog('close');
}
}

function SchemaViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.name = ko.observable();
self.tables = ko.observableArray();

self.selectedTable = ko.observable();
self.selectTable = function (p) {
    self.selectedTable(p);
}
}
```

Then this is binding code:

```
schema = new SchemaViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(schema);
```

There is a Master-Detail scenario where an unordered html list  is binded with selectedColumn field of tableViewModel.

When a list item is selected, in Detail view I can add plugins with an Add button that shows a Wijmo dialog.
This is the code of dialog:

```
<div id="dialogAddPlugin" title="Plugin editor" data-bind="with: newPlugin">
    <textarea data-bind="value: code, valueUpdate: 'input'"></textarea>
    <div>
        Name: <input data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
        <button id="btnSaveNewPlugin" data-bind="click: $parent.addPlugin">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that addPlugin method is never called even if view model appears to be correctly setted.

What's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in your javascript console when the dialog is rendered?

Comment: No. I'm using ko js extender for Chrome too but no errors are traced.

Comment: I don't see that you ever put anything into newPlugin.  You initialize it to an empty observable, but never set it to anything.  I think that may cause problems with your bindings inside the dialog since the context for binding it null.

Comment: You are right! This observation solved my problem. Please post your comment as an answer. Thank you